# Including jquery-sparkline with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, jquery-plugins

I'm struggling with my first attempt with webpack.

I'm getting the following error in the browser console.

```
ERROR TypeError: $(...).sparkline is not a function
```

This is my webpack.config.vendor.js code

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
//const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js/dist/zone',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'jquery',
    'jquery-sparkline',
    '.\\node_modules\\jquery-sparkline\\jquery.sparkline.js',
     '@angular/material',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    '.\\wwwroot\\assets\\styles\\style.scss',
    '.\\node_modules\\chartist\\dist\\chartist.css',
    '.\\node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css',
    '.\\node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css',
    '.\\node_modules\\angular-calendar\\css\\angular-calendar.css',
    '.\\node_modules\\dragula\\dist\\dragula.css',
    '.\\ClientApp\\styles.css',
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {

    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { "modules": true 
             },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js'],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20357
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']
                },
                //{
                    //test: /\.scss$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    //    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                    //    // use style-loader in development
                    //    fallback: "style-loader"
                    //})
                //}
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {

            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']
                },
                //{
                //test: /\.scss$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                //    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                //    // use style-loader in development
                //    fallback: "style-loader"
                //})
                //}
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

And this is my webpack.config.js code.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: true },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']
                },
                //{
                //    test: /\.scss$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                //        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                //        // use style-loader in development
                //        fallback: "style-loader"
                //    })
                //},
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'vendor.css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new CheckerPlugin()
        ]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts'
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/components/app.browser.module#AppModule'),
                    exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
                })
            ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.server.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

I've included jquery-sparkline but I still get that error. I can see the sparkline code inside vendor.js but it doesn't appear to make any difference.

I also looked at the vendor manifest file and it contains this but no other mention of sparkline.

```
"./node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js":{
         "id":101,
         "meta":{

         }
      }
```

I also don't understand why I had to put the ProvidePlugin below in both files. Surely once should be enough, but when it was only in the vendor file, I got browser errors saying that it couldn't find $.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's look like you are using angular-netcore.

This case, you need install `types` for sparkline, since not have ready yet, you have to create one.

`ClientApp/typings/sparkline/index.d.ts`

**index.d.ts**

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: ClientApp/typings/sparkline/index.d.ts
interface JQuery {
    sparkline(values?: string | Array<(string | number)>, opts?: sparkline.Settings): any;
}

declare namespace sparkline {
    interface Settings {
        type?: string;
        barColor?: string;
        width?: string | number;
        height?: string;
        lineColor?: string;
        fillColor?: string | number;
        chartRangeMin?: string | number;
        chartRangeMax?: string | number;
        composite?: boolean;
        enableTagOptions?: boolean;
        tagOptionPrefix?: string;
        tagValuesAttribute?: string;
        disableHiddenCheck?: boolean;
    }
}
```

next you need declare to global:

```
typings install --global --save file:./ClientApp/typings/sparkline/index.d.ts
```

if you don't have `typings`, you can install by

```
yarn install typings
```

and last add `jquery-sparkline` to `boot.browser.ts`

**boot.browser.ts**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery-sparkline';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.browser.module';
...
```

because `boot.browser.ts` is configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers.

**!!!IMPORTANT**

Don't put `import 'jquery-sparkline';` to app/component because we don't want inject to `boot.server` as well (will throw error cause Server-side prerendering).

Need full code example here: [dotnet-core-angular-sparkline](https://github.com/hendrathings/dotnet-core-angular-sparkline)

Comment: Amazing! Worked perfectly!